# WordPress - How to use ACF's Repeater to output image after every x post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a [page](http://www.ankitdesigns.com/demo/rawafid/about/management-team/) and I'm using a CPT to display my posts. After the second post I'd like to add an image and after four more posts I'd like to add another image.

In ACF I set up a repeater but I'm not sure how to execute it so it knows when I want to display the image, which is after the second post, and then after four more posts.

Here's my loop:

```
function management_team_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'management-team',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );
    $team_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $team_query->have_posts() ) :

        $html_out = '<article class="team-member box-center">';
        while ( $team_query->have_posts() ) :
            $team_query->the_post();

            $role = get_field( "role" );
            $name = get_field( "team_member_name" );
            $bio = get_field( "bio" );
            // $profile = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full'     );
            $flip = get_field( "flip_content" );
            // Do stuff with each post here
        $html_out .= 
        '<div class="meta-team box vc_col-sm-5 vc_col-lg-offset-1">
            <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle("hover");">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <h6>' . $role . '</h6>' . '<h4>' . $name . '</h4>' . $bio . '
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        Lorem Ipsum
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</article>';
    else : // No results
        $html_out = "No News Found.";
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
```

I provided a link to my working example, here's one to what I want it to look like, [check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Vcf.jpg).

Would it be best to use PHP to do some sort of count? I liked the idea of ACF because it would be easier for someone else to manage the photos from a custom field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a counter for this, the way I would suggest doing it would be declare a variable outside the loop e.g. $counter = 1;. Then inside the loop put $counter++, which incrementally increases it by 1 each time the loop is passed. Then it should be a simple case of comparing $counter to which ever intervals you want to display the ACF, e.g.

```
if($counter == 2 or $counter == 4){
    your acf stuff here;
}
```

edit:

```
if($counter == 2){
    //get row x
} elseif($counter == 6)
    //get row y
}
```

Comment: but if it's two different images can I use "or"? Like if in the area to do the acf stuff I am calling a custom field, how does it not repeat itself for both counts?

Comment: These operators could all be changed to be fair, == to === just because php has some odd differences between the two, and or to || because it's standard practice and people get mad.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand, are the ACF fields relating to the posts themselves?

Comment: If I'm right in thinking you want to get row 1 after the second post, and row 2 after the fourth, it would be an if{}else{} statement instead!

Comment: Not after the fourth, it would be 4 posts after the second. In the OP it has the image of what I'm trying to achieve. ACF was on the table because I want to make it easier for someone else to manage the photos if they need to.